# Java 8 how to check null values and get List of object?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've a below code written in Java and I wanted to use in Java 8. How can I do that?

Below code is within method:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("address");
query.fields().exclude("_id");

List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);

List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
if(!users.isEmpty()) {
    for (Address address : addresses) {
        addresses.addAll(country.getSubaddress());
    }
}
return address;
```

in Java 8

```
List<List<Address>> values = countries.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(x -> x.getAddresses()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I only want List of Address. How can I do that ?

Comment: How does this compile `for (Address address : users)`? Can you share the class model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of solving the problem:

```
List<Address> addresses = Optional.ofNullable(users)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(x -> x.getAddress().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Does `mongoTemplate.find` ever return `null`? I don’t think so and your old loop solution didn’t check it for `null` either. So don’t pollute the code with unnecessary `null`-checks. Instead of `Optional.ofNullable(users).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).stream()`, just use `users.stream()`

Comment: @Holger - Yes, mongoTemplate.find may return empty or null values if it doesn't find any record. Could you propose correct solution?

Comment: Why “empty or null”? Shouldn’t it decide for one behavior?

Comment: Because in mongo document, not all users have address, so query may not fetch address for those records

Comment: That doesn’t explain why it would return `null` instead of an empty list.

Comment: right, I just double checked, its returning empty list